# Create user group as subgroup in WebSphere 7 (Portal)

Tags: user-management, websphere-portal, websphere-7

In a portlet running on a websphere 7 portal server I want to create a new user group that is a subgroup of an existing group.

Here is the code (that I shortend as much as possible to keep the focus):

```
/* vars */
final PumaController controller = ...;
final PumaLocator locator = ...;
final PumaProfile pumeProfile = ...;
final groupCn = ... ;

/* code to add group */
final List<Group> parent = locator.findGroupsByAttribute("cn", CN_OF_GROUP);
final String parentDn = pumaProfile.getIdentifier(parent.get(0));
log.debug("creating new group with cn=" + groupCn + ", parentDn=" + parentDn);
newGroup = controller.createGroup(groupCn, parentDn, new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
```

The debug statement prints:

> creating new group with
>   cn=[groupCn],
>   parentDn=cn=[CN_OF_GROUP],o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm

The code DOES create a group. But it looks like the parentDN argument is ignored. The group is not created as a subgroup of parent, but it is created as a top level group. (Which is the same thing that happens if I pass null as parentDn).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing. I would raise a PMR if I were you.

If you configured federated security instead of standalone security please delete the file based realm by the way. You should always delete it when configuring federated security.